# Tensorflow NaN before softmax

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I'm using Tensorflow to train a neural based reinforcement learning agent. The idea is the following, first I train an LSTM (on real data, to begin with a human bias) to predict what may be the the future actions of the human. Then I use the cell state of my LSTM as a state for reinforcement learning.

However, I've noticed a tendency for the internal state to shift with time, and therefore, the internal state is not directly suitable for Reinforcement Learning. It is apparently a common problem which is addressed with the normalized layer LSTM. I tried the tensorflow implementation of the NL LSTM but now, I cannot train it since TF puts NaN weights at its output.

I use the ADAM optimize with and tried different weights, nothing changes, I also tried to increase the number of units in my LSTM with no improvement.

Does anyone see the problem in my code ?

```
with tf.variable_scope("system_lstm") as scope:
    no_units_system=128
    _seq_system = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, max_length_system, system_inputShapeLen], name='seq_')
    _seq_length_system = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size], name='seq_length_')

    cell_system = tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(
            no_units_system)

    output_system, hidden_states_system = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell_system,
        _seq_system,
        sequence_length=_seq_length_system,
        dtype=tf.float32
    )

    out2_system = tf.reshape(output_system, shape=[-1, no_units_system])
    out2_system =  tf.layers.dense(out2_system, system_outputShapeLen)

    out_final_system = tf.reshape(out2_system, shape=[-1, max_length_system, system_outputShapeLen])
    y_system_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length_system, system_outputShapeLen])

    softmax_system = tf.nn.softmax(out_final_system, dim=-1)  
    loss_system = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out_final_system, labels=y_system_))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-10)
    minimize_system = optimizer.minimize(loss_system)
```

Comment: One possible reason for NaNs in outputs is because you have NaNs input. Make sure you have no NaNs in input. Did you try clipping the gradients. You said "neural based reinforcement learning agent" do you mean DQN/DDQN with LSTM instead of NN ?

Comment: Is it possible that your network exploded due to large gradients?